# Where can one obtain jetutils.exe / LDBView.exe and does it stil apply to Access 2003?

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm trying to view a .ldb file, with something easier to read than notepad, and I understand there is a utility for doing this in `jetutils.exe` called `LDBView.exe`

However, the utility is not still obtainable from Microsoft.  The page where it is mentioned has a dead link to the file: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176670

Comment: At this point I'd settle for the md5 check sums so I can do an "Index of" search on Google...

Comment: the download link http://download.microsoft.com/download/access97/utility1/1/win98/en-us/jetutils.exe worked for me

Comment: Used Sean's link and was able to use LDBView to view a .laccdb file.  Couldn't actually see the user names but could see the host names they were logging in from.

Comment: Forgot to mention: To view the .laccdb file, I had to select All Files as the file type in the Open Database dialog, then browse to the .laccdb file directly.  Browsing to the parent database, the .accdb file, didn't work (even though the utility prompts you to select a database file).